# What kind of brakes are these?

Tags: brakes

I had my (Giants) bike shipped overseas and the company who shipped it took the back wheel off, and disconnected the brakes on the front. I’m trying to figure out what kind of brakes they are so I can then, figure out how to reconnect them.
[image]
Sorry about the rust it wasn’t that bad till they shipped it over seas.

Comment: Sidenote: Remember to close the quick release lever on the wheel. There is also so much rust on the noodle that it might be prudent to replace it. I’d also thoroughly check all other parts for rust and damage.

Comment: Thank you!  I’ll definitely have to check it for other rusty spots because that could be dangerous.

Comment: I think you should also flip the front wheel, I'd argue the it is installed "backwards", based on thread pattern. The "chevrons" should point forwards. On pavement and other non-loose surfaces it does not matter, but on loose dirt tracks, it makes the front of the bike a bit unstable as the tire slides more sideways. (When installed correctly, it slips more towards the centerline)

Comment: Sidenote: Based on the picture, the shipping must have been more than what the bike is worth. And yes, the front wheel is flipped and is currently loose (i.e. it could fall off if you ride as is) because the quick release is open.

Comment: Other side-note: The fork stanchions look quite deeply corroded as if they had been in a rather salty environment. If you ride the bike they may abrade the seals in a matter of minutes. It must have travelled on the deck of a cargo ship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are V brakes. You can put the "noodle", the metal bent part which has the cable inside it, over the "noodle holder" on the other brake arm. If it doesn't have enough clearance, you will find a barrel adjuster somewhere (usually at the lever), which you can "tighten" (rotate clockwise) to offer more space for the outer cable, which lessens the tension in the inner cable. Then when the noodle is connected, rotate the barrel adjuster counterclockwise to have enough clearance for good braking.

Note the barrel adjuster usually has not only the main screw but also a lockring. To turn it, you need to loosen the lockring and only then can you turn the main adjuster.

Comment: I've found the barrel adjuster doesn't have that much range. I often need to loosen that nut (on the right side) with a hex key to adjust the wire. If you do that, first screw the barrel adjuster all the way in (no screw showing). That allows you to tighten it up as the pad wears.